# using orderBy in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

just started Angularjs, I have a simple application where orderBy is not working. What is wrong here?

```
<body ng-init="names=['Ruby','Java','Oracle','Basic']">
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy:'name' | filter:name">{{name | uppercase}}</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orderBy filter will order an array of objects by a property within each member of the array.  So if you say orderBy: 'name' then each member of the array should have a property called name in it.  In your array there are no properties of name because your array contains Strings not Objects.  If your array looked like:

```
names = [ { name: 'Ruby' }, { name: 'Java' }, { name: 'Oracle' }, { name: 'Basic'} ]
```

Then it'd work.  Or you can change orderBy: 'name' to orderBy like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy | filter:name">{{name | uppercase}}</li>
```

Then it won't use a property of the member to order by and instead use the value of each member to order the array which is what you want with Strings.

Comment: How do I then do reverse orderBy?

Comment: You could try orderBy:null:true that's pretty close to what orderBy would cause.  Unfortunately the docs do not specify how to work with non-object types so even though that what I wrote works, its undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

The orderBy only works with arrays of objects -- See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy

I made a JSfiddle for you
http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/

```
$scope.names =[{name:'Ruby'}, {name:'test'},{name:'Oracle'},{name:'Basic'}];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Removed single quote from `name` and it started working. But not sure if I should stop using quotes?

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy:name | filter:name">{{name | uppercase}}</li>
```